# International pet travel and chips

Tags: pets

Our dog is chipped from the Humane Society.  On the same paper, they refer to the dog as a pit bull.  It's a pit bull mix.  The country we need to travel to occasionally has a ban on this kind of dog.  I think we can get a paper from the vet calling it something else.  But, if the chip number is referenced, they may see pit bull?  Does this put a hole in things?

Comment: How about getting a letter from your vet, and then seeing if the Humane Society can change their description to match.

Comment: It seems like this whole plan is missing the point: regardless of what the paperwork says, is the dog *actually* of a breed banned in the foreign country?  Their police and courts will have their own procedures for determining the breed of a dog, and I doubt they are required to accept what it says in the chip or in the vet's certificate.  For instance, they could have their own vet examine the dog. If they determine that it is a banned breed, what happens to you and your dog?  Nothing pleasant, I expect.

Comment: Probably _the dog_ gets refused entry and back on the next flight to wherever.

Comment: In any case, your pet might need a new microchip anyway. To travel to most countries, your pet will need an ISO 11784/11785 full duplex microchip. These were not commonly available in the US until a few years ago, and incompatible chips are still widely used (apparently most American pets don't travel far from home). Ask your veterinarian.

Comment: it's unfortunate the question does not mention which country going to / which country from